# convolution of two exponential signals with imaginary numbers

Tags: signal-analysis, convolution, linear-systems

I can solve problems without imaginary numbers, but when exponential contain imaginary numbers, I can't solve the problem.
For example, $x(t)=e^{3jt}+e^{4jt}$, $y(t)=(e^{-3t}-e^{-4t})u(t)$ (where $j$ is imaginary number and $u(t)$ is step function) I can't calculate $x(t)*y(t)$ easily.

In other problem that I can handle, I just easily calculate the integrals and make the answers, but with these imaginary numbers on the exponentials, I can't calculate the integrals even with the help of the calculator

can somebody help me?

Comment: Could you clarify the source of your confusion? In theory, you just apply the convolution formula, just as in the real case.

Comment: @MBaz First of all I can't solve this type of problem that contains an imaginary number so I just bring one case of the problem. If someone can show me how the way to solve that kind of problem, I can solve other problems on my own.

Comment: @linki *why* can't you solve it. It's just numbers. What's the problem here? you need to be a bit more specific, please :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah I edited few lines that make the question more specific. But the main problem is, I can't calculate this convolution :(

Comment: so, you know what the convolution is as a formula? Can you write down the formula? Why can't you just do *exactly* the same as for real exponents?

Comment: @linki Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_using_Euler's_formula